# Anonymous file and folder permission/owner

Tags: files, permissions, vsftpd

I've recently installed vsfptd on my server as I want to offer an ftp to several users.
I've decided that everyone would use it as an "**anonymous**". Every file/folder created/uploaded would however be owned by my account. To do that, I added the following files in my vsftpd.conf

```
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=frederic
```

Problem #1 : However, I am encountering issues where when I create a folder, the owner is not modified and is still "ftp".
[image]

Problem #2 : When I upload a file, the "chown" correctly works but the permissions are only set to the "user" (x-r) while it should be equal to rwxrwxr-x (as my anon_umask = 0002)
[image]

For information, here is an extract of my vsftpd.conf file :

```
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/home/frederic/Data
anon_other_write_enable=YES
anon_umask=0002
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=frederic
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,
After several hours of investigation/testing, I found the solution:

Commenting/disabling the

```
chown_uploads
```

made it work and now any change that I make on file_open_mode, anon_umask, etc... work !
Is that a bug ? I don't know but it fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

You also need to specify the file open mode:

```
file_open_mode=0777
```

The mask is exactly that, a mask, it turns bits off, not on.

Comment: I had tried that as well but no success....